# Regular expression..retrieve text and replace

Tags: java, regex

I have an xml file like:

```
<pre>
    <book category="CHILDREN">
      <details title="Harry Potter" author="J K. Rowling">
    </book>
</pre>
```

How can I use substring on the string (in the xml file) and replace the author with xyzName?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this? **You could get into legal trouble** *for not showing any code*. :P

Comment: What you are showing is not a well-formed xml document.

Comment: Don't use regular expression for this, use an appropriate DOM

Comment: You shouldn't `substring()` - use XML parser to do it!

Comment: print re.sub(r"author=.*",r'author="xyz">',x) in python.

Answer (score 0):

[If you would still like to use regex for this after noting the warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454),

Use the following regex replacement:

```
String contents = "<pre>\n" +
                      "<book category=\"CHILDREN\">\n" +
                        "<details title=\"Harry Potter\" author=\"J K. Rowling\">\n" +
                      "</book>\n" +
                  "</pre>";
String newContents = contents.replaceFirst("(?<=author=\")[^\"]+", "xyzName");
```

[View a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/aB2xY2/1)

**Expression explanation:**

- `(?<=author=\")` Asserts that our match is *after* char sequence **'author="'**.
- `[^\"]` Matches characters that are not **'"'**.

  - `+` Once or more [greedy: match as many as possible].